# try to run task n-times before throwing error

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I have method that is sending email using smtp server. Using `Task.Factory` I'm calling that method to not block UI:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail("mail@example.com", "Test title", "TEST body"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
.ContinueWith(p =>
        {
            if (p.IsFaulted)
            {
                if (p.Exception != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(p.Exception.ToString());
                }
                return;
            }
             MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Now I would like to modify my code to be able to try to call `SendMail` 10 times if something goes wrong. I've tried using do/while block, but I can't get this working:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool success = false;
        int i = 0;
        int max = 10;

        do
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail("mail@example.com", "Test", "TEST1"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
                .ContinueWith(p =>
                {
                    if (p.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        if (p.Exception != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(p.Exception.ToString());
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    success = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("ok");
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            i++;
        } while (!success && i < max);

        if (!success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ok", "success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private void SendMail(string address, string title, string body)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        MailClient.Instance.Send(address, title, body);
    }
```

That I would like to do is to be able to call Specific method inside task, if I get exception then I would like to call it again and again, 10 times, if after those 10 times it won't be successful I want to show exception.

Comment: I didn't read the code. I just want to tell, i know postsharp can do this easly if you like to check it out.

Comment: Just keep a count of how many times it has been called in a variable. If the count is less than 10, update the variable, otherwise throw the exception.

Comment: @Beakie I did that, but I get error in smtp client saying that I'm already calling method `send`, besides after calling my code I get `error` message.

Comment: @vgSefa - I would like to avoid buying extra components.

Comment: The loop won't work because you will instantly execute the end of the loop even while your first task is starting. In all likelihood, you finish your ten loops while the first send mail is still happening.

Comment: Maybe you better wrap with do-while only the `SendMail`?

Comment: @JoelC - that's what I thought. Any tips how to fix this?

Comment: @mazharenko nice idea, I'll try that, but I would like to know how to do that with tasks, because I won't be able to modify every method I would like to call this way.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TryAndRepeate(SendMail(...), 10), ...)`

Comment: @mazharenko hmm this looks interesting, any chances You could show me sample body of `TryAndRepeat`?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of @mazharenko and added a similar answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit off topic, but every time I see someone using threading for IO bound operations i get the chills :)

As sending mail is a network bound operation, you can use the awaitable [`SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922(v=vs.110).aspx) added in .NET 4.5.

If I may take the implementation posted by JoelC and refactor it a bit:

```
private int _maxAttempts = 10;

private async Task TrySendMailAsync(int attemptNumber)   
{
     var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
     var mailMsg = new MailMessage("from@test.com", "to@test.com", "Test Subject", "Test Body");

     while (!success && attempts <= maxAttempts)
     {
         try
         {
             await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg)).ConfigureAwait(false);
             success = true;
         }
         catch
         {
             if (attempts >= maxAttempts)
             {
                 throw;
             }
         }
         attempts++;
     }
}
```

This will let you loop as requested, but let the main job which is the async IO work without the unnessacery execution of a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might fix the issue:

```
    private int _maxAttempts = 10;

    private void TrySendMail(int attemptNumber)

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendMail("mail@example.com", "Test title", "TEST body"), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
        .ContinueWith(p =>
        {
            attemptNumber++;

            if (p.IsFaulted)
            {
                if (p.Exception != null)
                {
                    if (_attempts < _maxAttempts)
                    {
                        // Try again
                        TrySendMail(attemptNumber);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(p.Exception.ToString());
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
            success = true;
            MessageBox.Show("ok");
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Its not the prettiest and you want to watch that you don't call it recursively too many times and get a stack overflow! Ten times should be fine.

EDIT:
I changed the attempts count to an argument to be safer with threading, in case you are calling this send mail possibly on a thread many times.

EDIT2:

The implementation of the method @mazharenko mentioned above could look something like this:

```
private void TryAndRepeat(Action routine, int maxAttempts)
    {
        int attempts = 1 ;
        bool success = false;

        while (!success && attempts <= maxAttempts)
        {
            try
            {
                routine.Invoke();

                success = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (attempts >= maxAttempts)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            attempts++;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: won't calling same method from itself be dangerous?

Comment: The one danger is calling the same method too many times from itself causes your stack to run out of space. I don't think the threading should cause an issue because you're calling it again after you're done attempting to send mail already, since the call is in the `ContinueWith` However, mazharenko's comment above may hint at a nicer way to do it that contains everything in a single task, instead of nesting tasks.